# using child property to filter all parent objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, lodash

I'm trying to dive deeper into JavaScript and
came across a unique scenario whereby data is presented one way, but the display is reliant upon child properties dictating the organization of the parent. (* is there a term for that?)

How can I present this data so that it is arranged by "forms". And maybe its not about reversing the data as much as creating some sort of relation.

The result should be a clone . not mutate the original data.

either pure JavaScript OR _.lodash.

**A good answer will** suggest *the method* to manipulate the data so that it can be presented by forms.name.

**a superb answer will** demonstrate how (show code) to manipulate the data with forms.name.

Given the original data presented in this method.

```
parent : {
    childOne: {
        canHide : true,
        canStop : false,
        forms : [
            {name: 'pathway 1', enabled: true},
            {name: 'pathway 2', enabled: false},
            {name: 'pathway 3', enabled: false}
        ]
    },
    childTwo: {
        canHide : true,
        canStop : false,
        forms : [
            {name: 'pathway 1', enabled: true},
            {name: 'pathway 2', enabled: false},
            {name: 'pathway 5', enabled: false},
            {name: 'pathway 7', enabled: false}
        ]
    }
},
```

What I am trying to figure out is , how would I present the data more like this?

**NOTE: that child.forms.name may contain spaces.**

```
newParent : {
    pathway 1 : {
        childOne: { enabled : true },
        childTwo: { enabled : false }
    },
    pathway 2 : {
        childOne: { enabled : false },
        childTwo: { enabled : false }
    },
    pathway 3 : {
        childOne: { enabled : true },
    },
    pathway 5 : {
        childTwo: { enabled : false }
    },
    pathway 7 : {
        childTwo: { enabled : false }
    }
},
```

I'm not entirely sure this is how the data should be structured.

I'm trying to learn more JavaScript.

What I'm thinking the display would look like is this

```
Pathway 1
    childOne .     [checkbox] => enabled : true|false
    childTwo .     [checkbox] => enabled : true|false  
...  
Pathway 7
    childTwo .     [checkbox] => enabled : true|false
```

**So far I have tried:**

I did a for loop based on the length of forms.name within "parent" Object.
Push each forms.name into a new array.
used lodash uniq to return only unique ( deduplicate the array )

From there I was thinking there has to be a way to loop thru parent again , creating a new array where each child (childOne, childTwo, etc) is added under each form.name from the unique list.

But then I still need to return the "enabled" property.

**UGGGG there has to be a better way?**
I read something about relational databases. 
Is there some code like that where I would not have to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: You should share the code of what you've already tried! :)

Answer (score -1):

I played with your code and ended up with this:

```js
var parent = {
    childOne: {
        canHide : true,
        canStop : false,
        forms : [
            {name: 'pathway 1', enabled: true},
            {name: 'pathway 2', enabled: false},
            {name: 'pathway 3', enabled: false}
        ]
    },
    childTwo: {
        canHide : true,
        canStop : false,
        forms : [
            {name: 'pathway 1', enabled: true},
            {name: 'pathway 2', enabled: false},
            {name: 'pathway 5', enabled: false},
            {name: 'pathway 7', enabled: false}
        ]
    }
};
var newParent = {};

// Here comes the funk(tion)!
Object.keys(parent).map(function(child, index1) {
  var forms = parent[child]['forms'];
  Object.keys(forms).map(function(pathway, index2) {
    var pw_name = forms[pathway]["name"];
    newParent[pw_name] = newParent[pw_name] || {};
    newParent[pw_name][child] = { "enabled": forms[pathway]["enabled"] };
  });
});

// Output
console.log(newParent);
```

Feel free to comment if you want me to add something.

Anyway, I hope it helps!